# How to use subscription payment for downloadable products?

Tags: downloadable, magento-1.9.1.1

I have a Magento CE 1.9.1 web store for downloadable products (images) which can be purchased individually.

What do I need to do to make it possible for a customer to pay for a whole month or several months and then be able to download a certain (limited) amount of different images every day or week, or for the whole period. Basically - just like he would by using Shutterstock or similar with a subscription pre-payment.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Its little bit late to answering. 
But you can change downloadable links for every interval like below :

Mage_Downloadable_Model_Observer

```
/**
 * Save data from order to purchased links
 *
 * @param Varien_Object $observer
 * @return Mage_Downloadable_Model_Observer
 */
public function saveDownloadableOrderItem($observer)
{
    $orderItem = $observer->getEvent()->getItem();
    if (!$orderItem->getId()) {
        //order not saved in the database
        return $this;
    }
    $product = $orderItem->getProduct();
    if ($product && $product->getTypeId() != Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE) {
        return $this;
    }
    if (Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased')->load($orderItem->getId(), 'order_item_id')->getId()) {
        return $this;
    }
    if (!$product) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($orderItem->getOrder()->getStoreId())
            ->load($orderItem->getProductId());
    }
    if ($product->getTypeId() == Mage_Downloadable_Model_Product_Type::TYPE_DOWNLOADABLE) {
        $links = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getLinks($product);

        if ($linkIds = $orderItem->getProductOptionByCode('links')) {
            $linkPurchased = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased');
            Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset(
                'downloadable_sales_copy_order',
                'to_downloadable',
                $orderItem->getOrder(),
                $linkPurchased
            );
            Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset(
                'downloadable_sales_copy_order_item',
                'to_downloadable',
                $orderItem,
                $linkPurchased
            );
            $linkSectionTitle = (
                $product->getLinksTitle()?
                $product->getLinksTitle():Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::XML_PATH_LINKS_TITLE)
            );
            $linkPurchased->setLinkSectionTitle($linkSectionTitle)
                ->save();
            foreach ($linkIds as $linkId) {

                if (isset($links[$linkId])) {

           // ************** Make your changes here  ************
          // Here downloadable link with id 23 will assign to new order

                    if ($linkId == 23)
                    {
                        $linkPurchasedItem = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link_purchased_item')
                            ->setPurchasedId($linkPurchased->getId())
                            ->setOrderItemId($orderItem->getId());
                        Mage::helper('core')->copyFieldset(
                            'downloadable_sales_copy_link',
                            'to_purchased',
                            $links[$linkId],
                            $linkPurchasedItem
                        );
                        $linkHash = strtr(base64_encode(microtime() . $linkPurchased->getId() . $orderItem->getId()
                            . $product->getId()), '+/=', '-_,');
                        $numberOfDownloads = $links[$linkId]->getNumberOfDownloads()*$orderItem->getQtyOrdered();
                        $linkPurchasedItem->setLinkHash($linkHash)
                            ->setNumberOfDownloadsBought($numberOfDownloads)
                            ->setStatus(Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link_Purchased_Item::LINK_STATUS_PENDING)
                            ->setCreatedAt($orderItem->getCreatedAt())
                            ->setUpdatedAt($orderItem->getUpdatedAt())
                            ->save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Please try to override this event in your module first.